# Join two strings into a single decimal value

Tags: c#, floating-point, decimal

I want to get a decimal value, for example `500.45`, from two strings. How to achieve this operation?

```
decimal value; //like 500.45

string txt1, txt2;
txt1 = "500";
txt2 = "45";

value = Convert.ToDecimal(txt1) + Convert.ToDecimal(txt2); //500.45
```

Comment: `string txt1 = 500` What?

Comment: @SonerGönül, it's a typo, chill!

Comment: typo's can be considered errors if the OP copy's the code verbatim then they will usually complain that it didn't work if they are new to coding and not familiar with using Intellisense

Answer (score 0):

```
string txt1, txt2;
txt1 = "500";
txt2 = "45";

decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0}.{1}", txt1, txt2));
```

Comment: Don't forget to use a neutral culture or your separating dot will not read correctly on some systems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
decimal val;
string txt1 = "500";
string txt2 = "45";
string textValue = txt1 + "." + txt2;
decimal.TryParse(textValue, 
                 NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                 out val);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value = Convert.ToDecimal(txt1 + "." + txt2);
```

Comment: `+1` I agree there are many ways to skin a cat and still end up with pussy that purrs...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only answer everybody can come up with is the trivial one (concatenating with a dot in between and parsing it). But then *do it right*, please! (I gave enough hints!) On my system, for example, the decimal separator is a comma, so all your code will not work. You have to do it in a neutral culture, for example:

```
string integerPart = "500";
string fractionalPart = "45";

decimal result = Decimal.Parse(
    // Combine the strings to a new string "500.45"
    String.Format("{0}.{1}", integerPart, fractionalPart),
    // We allow a leading sign "-500.45", and a decimal point
    NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
    // We use a neutral culture in which the decimal separator is a dot (.)
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If the strings are user input, you should use `TryParse` instead and handle the case where it fails due to wrong user input:

```
decimal result;
if (!Decimal.Parse(
    String.Format("{0}.{1}", integerPart, fractionalPart),
    NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    out result))
{
    // Handle invalid user input.
}
```

Comment: I take your point but I have never once had to specify a culture when doing this type of conversion. In Holland this may be an issue. Here it's not. I don't generally configure my servers for dutch.

Comment: @Liam You don't have to configure your servers for Dutch (or any of those other languages that use decimal comma's), but you (as a good programmer) have to be aware that the conversion _will fail miserably_ on some non-US systems, and that this is solved very easily!

Comment: I do take your point, but describe a non-Us system and how would I come across these? I've never deployed code like this to a server where this would be an issue. PS I'm in UK so I'm using a non US system. What I'm saying is, just because you **have** to do it this way, does not make it *right* for everyone

Comment: @Liam It is exactly the opposite, IT DOES make it right for everyone.

Comment: @Liam You are actually doing the opposite: because you live in a decimal-dot country, you expect that to be right for everyone...? You don't know where anyone using this code lives, or how the OP will deploy the application that uses this code. You somehow expect the OP to live in the US _and_ to never run the code on a non-US system. That's just plain wrong.

Comment: @Virtlink, I don't live in the US, Jeez people, chill out

Comment: @Liam I know you live in Liverpool, I never said _you_ lived in the US. :P

Comment: @Virtlink Good point, but why do you need the NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign?

Comment: @TwoMore Of all the numberstyles enabled by `NumberStyles.Float`, _LeadingWhite_, _TrailingWhite_ and _Exponent_ didn't seem very relevant. Then only _LeadingSign_ and _DecimalPoint_ were left. Anticipating negative numbers, I put it in. It is not required.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the `string.Join()` Method to accomplish this too

```
string txt1, txt2;
txt1 = "500";
txt2 = "45";
var valueJoin = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Join(".", txt1,txt2));
```

`Output 500.45`

Comment: this answer is correct and not sure why someone would downvote it.. people should test what we have written here as answers before they downvote.. I actually tested the code it works otherwise I would not have added it as an answer..

Comment: -1: Your code does _not_ work on my system because in my default culture the decimal separator is a comma, not a dot. The result is `50045` which is obviously not correct. If I change it in your code to a comma, it will not work on your system.